# String comparison fails in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to build a small web app in python3 with Flask and I have a problem comparing two strings. For some reason, even if the strings are identical my function returns a false.

This is what I am trying to do:

I created a (question) form in HTML and I expect an answer from a user. When the user clicks 'Submit' a function is triggered in python that is supposed to compare the answer to the correct answer. If answer == correct_answer then a message is displayed "Excellent!!" if not something like "Try again".

```py
def compare(str1, str2):
   if str1==str2:
      message = 'Excellent'
   else:
      message = 'Try again'
   return message
```

Then I retrieve the answer from the web form and also my correct answer from a .txt file (this is a temporary file that will only contain the correct answer) and call the function:
...

```
answer=request.args.get('answer') #this works - value from the webform
f = open('temp.txt', 'r') #this works
correct_answer=f.read() #this works
f.close()

result=compare(answer, correct_answer) # this one always returns 'Try again'
```

So, the problem is that no matter what the answer is the result is always false.

Just to be sure that I have the same values I tried:

```
print(answer)
print(correct_answer)
```

and I have the same value, but the function returns false

I tried:

```
print(type(answer))
print(type(correct_answer))
```

The result is 'str' for both print.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: I'm guessing `f.read()` probably returns the answer, terminated with a newline character. `compare(answer, correct_answer.strip())` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that there are leading or trailing whitespaces or newlines in either of the strings, hence it might be better to strip those characters are then compare.

```
def compare(str1, str2):
   #Strip both strings before comparing
   str1 = str1.strip()
   str2 = str2.strip() 
   if str1==str2:
      message = 'Excellent'
   else:
      message = 'Try again'
   return message
```